# GUI to monitor and manage webserver rate limiting and blocklists

Tags: security, apache

There are various Apache modules that implement some kind of rate limiting.  Eg. **mod_security** or **mod_qos** and services like **stopforumspam** and other blacklists to detect malicious requests.

My question: Is there some software that lets me comfortably manage white- and blacklists, include data from outside sources together with a nice GUI?

For example I want to easily see the top requesting hosts and whitelist or blacklist them or their networks.  I want to be able to define IP blocks that are potentially less trusted than others and mark certain patterns in the request strings.

Is there a preferably open source, but not necessarily free, product that facilitates these tasks and integrates with Apache?